# wordpress metabox (plugin) display one page theme

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I m using the metabox plugin for wordpress
I want to get value from one or few metabox in my one page wordpress theme.
Here's how i get all my page

```
/set some variables
//get all the pages on your site
$contact = get_page_by_title( 'Contact' );
$pages = get_pages(array(
'sort_order' => 'ASC',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'exclude' => $contact->ID,
) );

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
  $title = $page_data->post_title;
  $slug = $page_data->post_name;
  $pageid=$page_data->ID;
  $couleur=rwmb_meta('twg_couleur');


    //Put a container around every page's content
      echo "<div class='container-fluid content $pageid' id='$slug'>";
      echo "<div class='container'>";


    //Heading and Content
    echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
    echo $content;
    echo $couleur;
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
;
```

But my var doesn't appears.
She's on the single page if I call her but seems to be empty or not there on the one page template.

How i can do that ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK !

I just use

```
$couleurs=rwmb_meta('twg_couleur','type=color' , $pageid);
```

AND

```
$pageid=$page_data->ID;
```

it's working
thanks to me :-)